# I can't extract this url with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Hi I try to extract url imagen with xpath. I 've xpathHelper extension in chrome
Html:

```
<source src="https://estaticos.test.com/test/117/452/img1.jpg">
```

In scrapy i try this

```
ml_item['img2'] = response.xpath(
        '//*/picture/source[2]/@src').extract()
```

and try

```
ml_item['img2'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/picture/img[1]').extract()
```

but dont works, return empty, in xpathhelper returns correct url.
 With other images url I hasn't got any problem.
I used with other images `ml_item['image_urls'] = response.xpath(
'//*[contains(@class,"detail-gallery")]/div/div/div/img/@src').extract()`
and it works

I use chrome and firefox

Comment: Hi! Could you give more details? Like, from which page you are trying to scrapy? And also the xpath selector of images that worked?

Comment: using chrome to check xpath isn't the best idea as elements are modified while page loads

Comment: I try crawl this [link](https://www.qdq.com/escuela-de-inteligencia-madrid-sur-120736) 
I grab all the images except the first one above the name. I try use Firefox but i hasn't got lucky

Comment: use scrapy shell "you_link" then `view(response)` to see what scrapy is actually getting and test your xpath there

Comment: In view(response) image dont load, this is the problem but i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this Xpath expression:

(//picture[@class='image-wrapper']/img)[1]/@src

Answer (score 0):

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="main-info"]//img[@class="image"]/@src').extract_first()
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solves the problem?

Comment: Thx, but dont works, Scrapy Shell view response cant load full page